# Stop Excel from converting data value to decimal number

Tags: excel

When I try to concatenate a 2 cells, one of which contains a date, i'm getting a number with decimals. How to remove those decimals? From the below image, I want the output to look like `Number:42952` but I get `Number:42952.625`. I don't see the decimals when I reference the cell though (see C2). How do I fix this?

[image]

Comment: I didnt see the comment. apologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
=CONCATENATE(A1&INT(A2))
```

or replace INT with ROUNDUP if you want the next day

Comment: Really? in favour of what?